# Listview.builder inside StreamBuilder is rebuilding/flickering

Tags: flutter, firebase, stream-builder

So I used Streambuilder to fetch CartItems from Firestore and it starting to flicker and it always goes to the top. Also can't scroll down, it always goes to the top, I used streambuilder in different parts of the app and it works perfectly but here it causing the problem...

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getCartStream() {
  CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")         
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)         
    .collection("cart");     
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> stream = ref.snapshots();     
  return stream;   
}

StreamBuilder(
  stream: getCarStream(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return Container();
  } else {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      ProductModel productModel = ProductModel.fromMap(snapshot.data!.docs[index].data());
    return CartItem(product: productModel);
  },
);
}
},
)),
```

[Rest of the code](https://pastebin.com/Qsj54Jd5)

[Gif of the Problem](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExMzkwN2MyYjliMjIyMDIwNDcyY2YyM2ZjYjEyYjZmNWJhYWI2ZmMwYyZjdD1n/FGY3OH4KSjMadMhgZC/giphy.gif)

Comment: are you using statefulwidget

Answer (score 0):

just remove the initState(), will work fine. if not then kindly share CARTITEM(..) class.

Comment: CartItem()--> https://pastebin.com/nCxxFMus

Comment: removed initState() same as before

Comment: CartItem() is fine, now made CartPage into stateless widget. let mw know, if error still exists.